# Vinculated boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem in the form:

$-y''(x)+V(x)y(x)=0 $

with the initial conditions: 
$\quad y'(0)=k \ y(0), \quad k=cte$

The $V(x)$ is a model's parameter, for example $V(x)=\frac{6}{\left(x+2\right)^2}$.

In order to resolve it numerically for a given input $V(x)$, i try to write:

```
k=-50;
s = NDSolve[{-y''[x] + v[x]*y[x] == 0, y'[0] == k*y[0]}, y, {x,0, 100}]
```

As NDSolve requires two initial conditions the message shows:

"*The number of constraints (1) (initial conditions) is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables (2). >>*"

How to use NDsolve with vinculated initial conditions?

Comment: This is the problem, i cannot impose a specifics values on the y'(0)  or y(0)  . The v[x] depends of a model and is numeracally envaluated.

Comment: maybe `s = ParametricNDSolve[{-y''[x] + v[x]*y[x] == 0, y'[0] == k*a, 
  y[0] == a}, y, {x, 0, 100}, {a}]`?